# Why does tapping on a Wi-Fi Network not do anything?

Tags: samsung, wi-fi

When I try to connect to certain Wi-Fi networks, it won't respond or try to connect. When I tap on the network name, it gives the selection animation, but it doesn't show the "**connecting...**" text or show that it's connected. Sometimes my network wouldn't even show up in the list. Every one of my other devices can connect to the network.

It seems to also happen in certain places in the building. When I put up my own hotspot on another device, it won't respond to that either.

I've got an unmodified non-root Samsung S10 with One UI version 4.1, Android version 12, and was just factory reset a few days ago

Any fixes?

Comment: Try forgetting the connection and then reconnect.